# bootstrap 4 button text alignment

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This should not be difficult, but it is driving me mad :D
I have a simple button (for testing purposes) just looks like this:

```
.btn-test {
  height: 100px;
}

<button class="btn btn-test">
  <span>This is a test</span>
</button>
```

If you are using bootstrap and run that bit of code, you will see this:

https://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/MPbryQ

As you can see, the text "This is a test" is vertically aligned. I have looked at the CSS for the button and I fail to see where this is set. I assume it's something to do with flexbox. I have tried adding `align-items-start` to the button classes, but nothing changes.

Surely someone knows how to align the text to the top or bottom easily?

Comment: There are lots of different ways to get the text to the top or button of the button. But it all depends on what you trying to do with the button. A simple way would be to just use `padding-top` or `padding-bottom`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add `.d-flex` in the button, after that you can apply the other positioning classes such as `.align-self-start`, `.align-self-end`, `.align-self-baseline` etc to the span, this will position the text accordingly.

and even if you don't apply the `.align-self-start` it will be default positioned at top.

```
<button class="btn btn-test d-flex">
    <span class="align-self-start">This is a test</span>
</button>
```

this should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS property `line-height`. Change to whichever value (height) you want.

```css
.btn-test {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 150px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn btn-test btn-primary">
  <span>This is a test</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that buttons in bootstrap are flex boxes. Any way, I tried this and this puts the text on the top of the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-test d-flex align-items-start">
  <span>This is a test</span>
</button>
```